# Single Sign on with SAML and shadow copies of the user data

Tags: single-sign-on, saml

In advance apologies for the english.

For a client we have to built a Single Sign On option. The client asked for SAML specifically. The client keeps track of all the information. For so far I understand SAML they will be the Identity Provider and we will be the service provider.

However for our system to function we need to have a user. So our system needs to hold the same information as the identity provider. Out thoughts were to make shadow copies in our system and update the information on SAML login. But this seems counter intuitive to SAMLs principles. Is this even the right way to do this? Or should we take another approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The use case is sometimes referred to as 'auto-federation'. The SP creates and updates identity information within its identity silo. This is quite common.